# Dustjs: what about performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js

I like syntax of [this template library](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/) for JS. I'm going to use it in Node.js script, so, performance is quite important. Have anybody tried this one? (Their web-site works too slow to make me think their library works fast enough :) ).

Comment: Thanks for posting this; that looks like an awesome library :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Live performance comparisons of dust to other templating engines: http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/benchmark/index.html. It basically blows the other libraries away (Mustache, Handlebars, and jQuery Templates).

If you aren't satisfied with those results, [roll your own benchmark](http://jsperf.com/).

---

As for the slowness of the Dust "website" — it's just a [github project page](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/). I didn't notice any performance issues with the site.

Comment: I'm affriad, I haven't found what does "string" and "replace" benchmarks mean? Because in all others it shows really great perfomance. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the source code of the test suites for each library: [dust_suite.js](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/benchmark/suites/dust_suite.js) [mustache_suite.js](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/benchmark/suites/mustache_suite.js) [handlebars_suite.js](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/benchmark/suites/handlebars_suite.js) [jQuery_suite.js](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/benchmark/suites/jquery_suite.js)

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer, checkout their [**benchmarks**](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/benchmark/index.html). 
  The results are pretty staggering.

Answer (score 1):

According to many tests on jsperf such as [JavaScript template language shootoff](http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml-based-templating/96) the recommended answers get "blown" away by other template engines. I use doT as it can be customized to use <% %>, <%= %> and <%- %> tags.

Comment: It seems to be at least twice faster then Dust, but I find it less easy-to-use and awesome in comparation with Dust. And finally, I have already fall in love with Dustjs, so syntax of doT seems to me quite shabby. That's the first library I like for it's syntax - usually I don't care. :) But thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I added Dust to the shootoff

http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml-based-templating/281

Even precompiled Handlebars is 3x faster than Dust. I like Dust's syntax too, and I'm currently using it to build a product, but will probably switch to Handlebars if not DoT.

The thing about Dust is that it's super easy to precompile since blocks and partials simply use other templates interchangeably, while Handlebars and DoT require "Helper" and "Blocks" to be registered separately.

I wish there were scripts out there to pre-compile Handlebar template files and detect helpers/blocks. There's very little CLI documentation.